# Is view faster than a natural join in Oracle? what about postgresql?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, oracle9i

```
SELECT cec.*
  FROM mam.category cec


SELECT cec.year, ces.*
  FROM mam.subcategory ces
  JOIN mam.category cec ON CEC.CATEGORY_ID = CES.CATEGORY_ID


SELECT cec.year, ceo.*
  FROM mam.options ceo
  JOIN mam.subcategory ces ON CES.SUBCATEGORY_ID = CEO.SUBCATEGORY_ID
  JOIN olr.iep_cost_est_category cec ON CEC.CATEGORY_ID = CES.CATEGORY_ID
```

According to a friend, views in oracle are actually faster for cache purposes. Is this true? What about postgresql? I've tried google and stackoverflow (closest one is MS SQL).

Comment: There are no natural joins shown, just regular inner joins.  For the joins to be 'natural', you'd have to include the word NATURAL (and for them to be outer joins, you'd include one of the keywords LEFT, RIGHT or FULL, plus the optional keyword OUTER).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Views

Views, which means non-materialized views, are not cached.  They are simply a prepared SQL statement that is run in place of the view reference in a query.  Think of them like macros, or variables holding the SELECT statement contained in the view.

Materialized views (not supported by PostgreSQL) are similar to tables because they can be indexed.  But materialized views are notoriously restricted (IE: no non-deterministic values) in what they can support.

### Natural JOINs

None of the examples you posted are natural JOINs, which look like this:

```
      SELECT cec.year, ces.*
        FROM mam.subcategory ces
NATURAL JOIN mam.category cec
```

The syntax is frowned upon (though being ANSI) because it's ambiguous at best and leaves you open to problems if:

- columns get added or renamed
- no more than two tables can be joined using this method
- gives you little control over the specifics of a join if columns join across the tables in an unusual way. It's not obvious what the join criteria is -- being explicit is both readable and guarantees consistent results.

### Conclusion

Non-materialized views are largely irrelevant with regard for JOIN syntax.  Data and indexing will have a larger impact on performance.

Comment: "The syntax is frowned upon": I was hoping you were referring to the `SELECT *` rather than `NATURAL JOIN`: "The natural join is arguably one of the most important operators since it is the relational counterpart of logical AND (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). With a well designed schema (e.g. consistently good data element naming, FK constraints, etc) they the joins are very readable and consistent.

Comment: @onedaywhen: AskTom on NATURAL JOIN: [forget it exists](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8764523461767).  SO questions should demonstrate that few build well designed data models.

Comment: have you seen the flip side of the coin? "The Importance of Column Names" ("http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Importance-of-Column-Names.pdf).

Comment: "SO questions should demonstrate that few build well designed data models" -- what I see is folk having a hard time writing good SQL DML because they didn't write good SQL DDL.

Answer (score 6):

Views can sometimes help with caching **slightly**.
The basis is that

```
SELECT a.name, b.zipcode 
FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id
```

is a different query from

```
SELECT a.name, b.zipcode 
FROM table_b b JOIN table_a a ON a.id = b.id
```

even though they are logically identical. If both get sent to Oracle, they both end up in the query cache. [The query cache is where Oracle stores queries so it doesn't have to repeat syntax/permission checks and the calculation a query execution path.] By having a view that encapsulates the join between table_a and table_b, there's less chance of multiple queries ending up in the cache that are logically identical.

This is part of a more generic principle of "Don't repeat yourself". If you repeat code, you need to repeat testing and patching and you have more code that can go wrong. Any performance benefit is a bonus. So there are benefits to views, but performance isn't a significant one.